# How to blur content behind div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blur Img's & Div's in HTML using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514954/blur-imgs-divs-in-html-using-css)

So basically what I want to do is to blur content witch is behind a `div` element, that `div` is with opacity 0 - 0.5.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KqB8/9/)

**EDIT[1]:** What I actually want is that a `div` goes over an image and the area under the `div` is blured.
**EDIT[2]:** `div`  with `position: absolute` goes over other elements and blur's them.

Comment: [this blog post](http://drublic.de/blog/effects-for-the-web/) might help

Comment: [HTML5 Please](http://html5please.com/) recommends you don't. The filter spec isn't even in Working Draft status.

Comment: @MrOBrian yes it is somewhat showing my retreat solution, but not the real one.

Comment: Consider using iframes that are blur-ed that 'scrollspies' the parent -- its a little hacky but here's a working demo in chrome -- https://s3.amazonaws.com/blur-demo/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should blur image on upload. Then crop other image on upload (or crop it using jQuery/css). Then combine what you have to achieve this effect.

Using css for this task is impossible. Using javascript for this task is bad idea (very slow).

Only option is to use [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemBlur/) technique on background image and then place another (cropped with js/upload) ontop of it.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the answer by [Purmou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515050/1494505) referenced in the comment by @Keith Nicholas, you could do something like:

```css
topblur{
    position: absolute;
    top:2px;
    left:2px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-image:url(http://www.stefanides.com/home/yard/back%20yard.jpg);
    opacity: 40;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); 
    border: thin solid black;
}
```

Not a great solution, but it does mess the image up!

Comment: Well what you are suggesting that I animate at the same time like four different `div` elements over the given position to simulate blur effect, not to mention that I need to render image position in `div` witch is going over the image. But what I really want is that any element under given `div` is blurred.

Comment: No.  Not suggesting animating anything.  Just trying to suggest what you want- laying a div over the div to be blurred.  The layover div is just the same image shifted a couple of pixels.

Comment: Well that's a good idea if the image and `div` are both in static positions. But what I want is bit more like magnifying glass.