# Html css blur effect in divs

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website but there is a problem ,there is need of Gaussian blur in a div, I can do change the opacity but not able to make the text blur in that.

Please help me

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="blur" style="">hellokkksdjfdshfshifsd isjfcsdkcjsdlk</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this method http://css-tricks.com/fun-with-blurred-text/

Comment: Using HTML5 and CSS3, your answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514954/blur-imgs-divs-in-html-using-css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply a CSS filter to a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-filter-to-a-background-image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not Possible directly, though can be achieved using css text-shadow. The trick is to make the text transparent and then give it a shadow

```
Selectortoblurtext
{
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
}
```

Try different combinations in shadow!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using text-shadow here like so:

```
#blur {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zmXrd/)

Answer (score 0):

You can place the following code in your style file

```
#blur {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

or just place

color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

in style="" tag.

the 0.5 is the opacity ratio, and the 0,0,0 are the rgb color values .