# blurred effect under fixed bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to blur the content as it passes under my fixed navbar, but I'm unable to blur anything...here is my latest [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/gzacycxt/11/) attempt:

I'm assuming I need two layers, a top layer for the text and a lower transparent layer that blends the content underneath. This is what my css looks like:

```
.navbar {
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: .94;
}

.navbar-fixed-top-glass-layer {
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 998;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

I've posted a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/gzacycxt/10/) of the desired effect I'm trying to achieve with bootstrap

Any thoughts?

Comment: Here's a great solution provided for the type of effect which you're trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19484879/2115001

Comment: @Fahad Hasan Your link also blurs the text in the navbar which is what I don't want to do. Please see the desired effect I posted in the second fiddle.

Comment: Please check this, http://jsfiddle.net/nallenscott/WtQjY/41/. This reflects the same behaviour as your second fiddle.

Comment: @Fahad Hasan Your example blurs the text on the header when I add it.

Comment: the blur filter only blurs elements that are children of that element

Comment: @Markasoftware Should I create a third layer that passes under the navbar in order to have it blurred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't add a comment to y'all's current discussion because my reputation. Fahad's answer is right though, just add a fixed position div with a higher z-index for the content you want over your blurred header

**jsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/WtQjY/415/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>          
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar {
    width: 75%;
    text-align: justify;
    min-width: 500px;
    margin: 1% auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10000000001;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

#navbar:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Could've made it prettier, but I got excited :P

Comment: I think the OP is using Twitter Bootstrap so this solution may not work.