# Creating a milk glass effect like in iOS 7 or Windows 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a header-block on my website which has a solid background-color with an opacity of 75%. This header-block has a fixed position and if I'm scrolling downwards, the content is barely visible behind this block - this was my intention. But now I additionally want to blur the content right behind the header-block.

I've seen this tech-demo: http://codepen.io/Edo_B/pen/cLbrt

Basically it provides what I need but the huge disadvantage is, that this is only working on webkit browsers.

I've also checked out blurjs which only lets me blur the background-image.

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the CSS property .blur? It seems that's all they're using to blur the image in the background. [Blur tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514954/blur-imgs-divs-in-html-using-css)

Comment: Yeah, this might work in all current browsers - but how do I say to blur a specific region of an element? I just want to blur the content behind the header-block but not the rest of the content.

Comment: I was thinking about that issue too. What's your website? from the codeopen link you provided, it *seems* like you can specify a rect area and blur that.

Comment: for -moz-: http://jsfiddle.net/3d6J9/

Answer (score 1):

### [Solution using Canvas Element](http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/ldimh/)

The only way I've found to solve your problem uses a canvas element to render the image and blur the desired area.
I'm using [this library](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html) that's very simple to use. It takes a `<img>` source element, a target `<canvas>` element and a blur radius. Here is the all the code:

#### HTML

```
<img id="bkg" src="...">
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```

#### CSS

```
#bkg, #can {position: absolute;}
```

#### JS

```
stackBlurImage('bkg', 'can', 5, false); //the blur
var canvas = document.getElementById('can'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in'; //clip
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(300,300,150,0,Math.PI*2,true); //a circle
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath;
```

If you are not familiar with canvas you can take a look at [this cheat](http://techtrends.eu/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/HTML5_Canvas_Cheat_Sheet1.png)