# Canvas blur div element

Tags: html, image, canvas

Is it possible to create a blur div with canvas?
On the internet i found only with an image, but i am looking for a code without an image.

```
<div class="element_one" id="blur_this"></div>
```

Comment: You can [fetch all the div's html elements and try to draw them on the canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) but this gets problematic with complex CSS. You might also check out [this CSS blur tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/14/item-blur-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/) that is linked in [this prior Stackoverflow Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514954/blur-imgs-divs-in-html-using-css/8515089#8515089).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/zk7313dz/

css

```
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height= 400px;
}

.blur{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  width: 400px;
  height= 400px;
}
```

Just use the built in `blur` that CSS already has :)

Comment: IE & Edge don't yet support `filter` (and Android only recently supports it) so please be sure you warn the viewers when you propose a solution that is not fully cross-browser compatible. ;-)

Comment: I did not know that @markE but do understand you feel/think you have a better answer than to leave this user hanging around for an answer please go ahead and provide one. I was just trying to help someone out in the spirit of niceness

Comment: Using a `filter` is a good answer. :-) But please be sure you give a "heads up" when proposing a solution that uses emerging browser capabilities -- that's all.

Comment: Is it possible without css blur filter, and only use canvas?