# Show Image with Blur Effect

Tags: javascript, css, image

I am looking for render image with blur effect in photo gallery.

For example I have HTML

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <img>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now what happens if image is heavy then it shows blank for corresponding element. I wants to maintain 2 versions of each image blury version and sharp version.

Now I wants till sharp image gets loaded completely show blury image of that image and once sharp image loaded show sharp image.

I can do it with onload event like keep 2 image tags one with blury image and another with sharp and show by default blury one image and on load event of sharp image hide blury one and show sharp one.

I wants to understand best optimal practice to achieve this behavior in smooth way.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514954/blur-imgs-divs-in-html-using-css

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin It's not a duplicate IMHO, he's asking about image loading optimalization and by *blurry* he probably means pixelated, or with less quality to enable faster load than the original photo..

Comment: You're right, my mistake!

Comment: Thanks everyone for sharing your ideas , it will help me to implement optimized...

Answer (score 2):

I created this https://jsfiddle.net/j8fnomse/3/

Blur effect you can achieve with css3 filters

```
.slow {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px)
}
```

You load each image separately

```
var slowImage = new Image();
slowImage.src = slow;
var fastImage = new Image();
fastImage.src = fast;
```

Once they load, you add them to the DOM, and you can add blur to the slower one.

```
$(fastImage).load(function(){
    if(!$img.attr("data-loaded"))
        $img.attr("src", slowImage.src).addClass("slow");
});
$(slowImage).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function() { // only to slow things down for demonstration
        $img.attr("src", slowImage.src).removeClass("slow").attr("data-loaded", true);
  }, 2000);
});
```

You should also check, if the faster image has not loaded first, I do check it with `data-loaded` attribute. When slower image loads, it adds `data-loaded` attribute. When slower image loads, it checks, if it has `data-loaded` attribute. If it has, it wont change the image to faster one.

Comment: does it make loaded twice?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping 2 image tags, just keep 1 image tag for blurry image in HTML.
Then create another image element and set sharp image source using javascript as follows -

```
var img= document.createElement('img');
img.src= src;
```

Now use onload event of this dynamically created image to replace the blurry image in HTML with sharp image.

This way, you won't have 2*n images in photo gallery.

Answer (score 0):

- Load lightweight image initially but also keep `data-src` which will hold the `heavy` image path in attribute.
- On `window.onload`, iterate all the images in the container and load the image whose path is stored in `data-src`
- Change the `src` of the image once large image is loaded.

Try this:

```js
$('#parentElement').find('img').each(function() {
  var img = new Image();
  var elem = $(this);
  img.onload = function() {
    elem.attr('src', this.src);
  }
  img.src = elem.attr('data-src');
});
```